# URI must be a string or UriInterface in laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

Currently, I m having a strange issue on php code. I am trying to acess my external service through rest api via `GuzzleHttp\Client` as rest client.
When I assigned `$url` as the following code:

```
$url ="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/auth";
Log::debug($url);
$request = new Request("POST", $url, [], json_encode($object));
return self::getClient()->post($request);
```

It will print the following log

```
[2018-12-09 20:46:21] local.DEBUG: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/auth
```

which will result in following exception

```
InvalidArgumentException URI must be a string or UriInterface
```

Comment: Try using this one $request = new \Illuminate\Http\Request();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
return self::getClient()->post($request);
```

With

```
return self::getClient()->send($request);
```